# Create new columns and fill values base on a structured text column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column of text in a structured format. I am hoping to find the most efficient way to expand that column to create new columns and fill the resulting cells based on information housed in the text.

More specifically the original data set is as such:

```
Summary
Category1 [Status1]; Category2 [Status2]
Category3 [Status3]; Category1 [Status4]
```

I'd like to have the data transformed to preserve the original column, but add on columns that would look like:

```
Category1    Category2     Category3     Category4
Status1      Status2
Status4                    Status3
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can you show us the sample data as dict ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I fully understand, do you mean to try and convert the text into a dictionary?

Comment: df.head().to_dict()

Comment: It doesn't convert well, the raw output has the index as keys and the whole cell's content as values, for example:

`{
  0: 'Category1 [Status1]; Category2 [Status2]'
  1: 'Category3 [Status3]; Category1 [Status4]'
}`